# Elements With name Attributes Going to Server: PHP Convention Only?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Many places have said that only elements with a `name` attribute go to the server on page change, and only the element name and its `value` attribute's value travel between client & server. Is this a `PHP` feature or is it also present in other scripting languages? For example, is this the case with `Node.js`, or any of its popular server frameworks like `express` or `grunt`? Also, are there ways to send other elements or attributes to the server?

I know that `AJAX` can cause pretty much anything to go to the server, but this is usually asynchronous, and even when it isn't the info doesn't usually go to the server right when the page is sent. If you have any relevant info on `AJAX`, though, please share it.

Comment: You must learn something about HTML forms. Form data goes to HTTP server, no matter what technology is there on the server.

Comment: Many more things than just the name of the input in the form are sent to the server. Cookies, IP address, etc

Comment: Yes, but I believe only stuff in forms is sent **when the page changes**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give an element a `name` attribute, the browser will send the form data in the body of the request (if using POST) or in the query string (if using GET). This happens no matter what language or framework you use.

`name` is the only attribute that does this - it will not work with an `id` - but you can also do this with AJAX, by passing a querystring to `XMLHttpRequest.send` (if you're using jQuery, read up on `jQuery.post`). Requests via AJAX are, to the server, identical to requests from the client. If you send data in an AJAX POST request, it will be identical to a request via an equivalent form to the server. This is the same whether you're using PHP, Node.js, or any other web framework.

Helpful references:

- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: To be honest, I was hoping for more history and whys. I suppose I'll ask another question or research. Thanks for the info, anyway.

Comment: What kind of history & whys are you looking for? I might be able to help.

Comment: Let me just ask the question, then I'll put a link in a new comment.

Comment: Just posted a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986688/why-are-forms-so-important-in-html. People don't seem to like it, though.